# Recreating Phone SMS UI with CSS: Absolute Positioning Conversation to Bottom while Maintaining Scroll

Tags: javascript, css

Working in a hackathon and we are having an issue with our phone mockup. We want to anchor the text stream to the bottom: seems like a great opportunity for position: absolute...right? Well that makes it so that our scrolling doesn't work.  Right now it is anchored to the top, positioned relative, and scrolling does work.

Try clicking the "I said..." button a few times. Ideally those buttons should be anchored (along with the text boxes that appear) to the bottom.

This is the temporary URL:

http://gotinto.com/text/

AND a PERMANENT JS Fiddle URL:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qyn7V/

Here is the simple HTML:

```
    <div class="convoPhone">
    <div class="phoneDisplay">
    <div class="convoCont">
    <div class="actualConvo">...(the actual text convo goes here)...</div></div></div></div>
```

Any solutions? We would be open to javascript, CSS, any combination. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your use of a temporary URL means that this question becomes useless/nonsensical to future visitors when that page dies, or is fixed. Please post the relevant [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code *here* (in your question) and (*ideally*) post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can play, and work, with. Help *us* to help *you*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up positioning the buttons absolute, then using a bit of jquery/javascript to make a minimum height.  Thanks for your help everyone!

```
var contH = $('.phoneDisplay').css('height');
    if($('.convoCont').css('height') < contH) {
        $('.convoCont').css('height',contH);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried position: fixed? Observing your link, as a proof of concept, something like this should do:

```
<div class="addLine" style="position: fixed; bottom: 60px; width: 290px;">
```

Edit: 
Put three place holder conversations as place holders with visibility: hidden (this ensures they occupy space).

```
<div class="convoCont">
    <div class="actualConvo" style="">
        <div class="invisibleFirst">
            <div style="visibility: hidden;" class="textInputCont isaid"><div class="author">Me:</div><textarea class="isaid"></textarea><div class="delete">Remove</div></div>
            <div style="visibility: hidden;" class="textInputCont isaid"><div class="author">Me:</div><textarea class="isaid"></textarea><div class="delete">Remove</div></div>
            <div style="visibility: hidden;" class="textInputCont isaid"><div class="author">Me:</div><textarea class="isaid"></textarea><div class="delete">Remove</div></div>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <div class="addLine" style="position: fixed; bottom: 60px; width: 290px;">
        <div class="isaid textLine">I said...</div>
        <div class="tsaid textLine">They said...</div>
    </div>
    <br class="clear">
</div>
```

Then for each of the first 3 real entries, remove one of the  place holders. If you want more precision, you can replicate the same place holder effect with padding-top on **actualConvo**. Just reduce the padding-top by a fixed value until it bottoms out at 0. If you want to make the buttons scrollable, just removed the styling and apply the padding-top at a higher DOM level.

Comment: We want everything that appears above it to also be anchored to the bottom, not just those buttons. Thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: Interesting. My understanding was that position fixed positions things relative to the browser window, not to elements in the page. So it seems like that would not work in this instance.  Am I incorrect?

Comment: Yes. Restructure your buttons to flow after the conversation portion if you want to maintain position when scrolling the page.